# Highcharts js grafica en tiempo real mysql y php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, highcharts

Hola estoy tratando de hacer una grafica con la libreria Highcharts en tiempo real que extraiga los datos desde mysql ya me muestra los datos pero aun no me da en tiempo real

Soy nueva con esta libreria y aun no domino bien el php y ya llevo lidiando mucho tiempo con este problema agradezco al que me pueda ayudar con esto.

Este es mi codigo:

El script:

```
<script>
    Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'spline',
    animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
    marginRight: 10,
    events: {
      load: function () {
      }
    }
  },

  time: {
    useUTC: false
  },

  title: {
    text: 'Live random data'
  },

  accessibility: {
    announceNewData: {
      enabled: true,
      minAnnounceInterval: 15000,
      announcementFormatter: function (allSeries, newSeries, newPoint) {
        if (newPoint) {
          return 'New point added. Value: ' + newPoint.y;
        }
        return false;
      }
    }
  },

  xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    tickPixelInterval: 150
  },

  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: 'Value'
    },
    plotLines: [{
      value: 0,
      width: 1,
      color: '#808080'
    }]
  },

  tooltip: {
                headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br/>',
                pointFormat: '{point.x:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}<br/>{point.y:.2f}'
            },
 legend: {
    enabled: false
  },

  exporting: {
    enabled: false
  },

  series: [{
    name: 'Temperatura',
 data: (function() 
 { var data = [];

  <?php for($i = 0 ;$i<count($rawdata);$i++){ ?>

   data.push([
    <?php echo $rawdata[$i]["date"];?>,
   <?php echo $rawdata[$i]["temperature"];?>
]); 
<?php } ?>  return data;
    }())
  }]
});

</script>
```

Y el php:

```
<?php 
$sql = "SELECT temperature,date, chipId from dht_log  WHERE chipId='2515633' ORDER BY `date` DESC ;"; 
        
$rawdata = getArraySQL($sql); 

for($i=0;$i<count($rawdata);$i++){ $date = $rawdata[$i]["date"]; 
$date = new DateTime($date); $rawdata[$i]["date"]=$date->getTimestamp()*1000; } ?>
```

Y esto es lo que me arroja, si no que no se actualiza como en el ejemplo que estoy siguiendo https://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-update
[image: Grafica]

Comment: Siguiendo el ejemplo que citas, quitaste exactamente el fragmento del setInterval que define el intervalo de actualización.

Comment: Realmente no es la forma correcta de hacerlo. Deberias tener un php que retorne un json con la data y que el javascript haga peticiones ajax al php y se repita con el interval.

Comment: @Alfabravo muchas gracias pero ya volví a poner esa parte del código y aun no se actualiza como es debido solo aparece como antes y con una linea nueva en la parte inferior de la grafica, alguna otra idea?

Comment: @LaFortuna eso ya lo había intentado y me extraía los datos de mysql pero no conseguí tener la fecha actual si no que mostraba una linea del tiempo desde 1970 al 2020 y con este nuevo código si me dio pero aun nada con lo de que se actualice en tiempo real

Comment: Es que primero toca entender bien el ejemplo para poderlo ajustar a lo que necesitas. El ejemplo usa datos aleatorios. LO que te dicen en el otro comentario es cierto y el PHP debería entregar los datos en un intervalo. La parte javascript se encarga de recibir eso cada vez (con el setInterval) y actualizar el array de puntos a graficar usando push.

Comment: Quizas por el formato de la fecha. Reparar la fecha sera mas sencillo. De todas formas, con interval y ajax es la forma de asimilar el realtime.